# Installing ghostscript using MacPorts fails

Tags: macos, install, xcode, macports

I recently upgraded MacOSX to version 10.9. Before I did that, i uninstalled all macports-packages using:

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependencies installed
```

Now I'm running MacPorts 2.2.1 and Xcode 5.0.2 is installed On my Computer. I'd like to install ghostscript (actually I'd like to install inkscape, but the installation of ghostscript fails) using the following command:

```
sudo port install ghostscript
```

But I receive the following error:

```
--->  Extracting ghostscript
Error: org.macports.extract for port ghostscript returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port ghostscript for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port ghostscript failed
```

The last lines of the log file (`cat /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/main.log`) contain:

```
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (ghostscript)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (ghostscript)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (ghostscript)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (ghostscript)
:debug:extract extract phase started at Tue Dec 17 13:31:36 CET 2013
:notice:extract --->  Extracting ghostscript
:debug:extract Executing org.macports.extract (ghostscript)
:info:extract --->  Extracting ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz
:debug:extract setting option extract.args to '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/ghostscript/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz'
:debug:extract Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
:debug:extract Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/ghostscript/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf -'
:debug:extract Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/ghostscript/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:info:extract sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory
:info:extract gzip: error writing to output: Broken pipe
:info:extract gzip: /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/ghostscript/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz: uncompress failed
:info:extract Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/ghostscript/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:info:extract Exit code: 127
:error:extract org.macports.extract for port ghostscript returned: command execution failed
:debug:extract Error code: NONE
:debug:extract Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:extract Warning: targets not executed for ghostscript: org.macports.activate org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:extract Please see the log file for port ghostscript for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/main.log
```

I couldn't find out what wrong,...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that macports is trying to use /usr/bin/gnutar, but can't find it. I think this happens because your version of macports was not built for mavericks, and therefore doesn't know where the tools (such as gnutar) actually are. There are different versions of macports 2.2.1, depending on your version of OS X.

You should reinstall macports (for mavericks) from the binary here: https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.2.1-10.9-Mavericks.pkg

you should probably also run `xcode-select --install`

Comment: and see the [Migration guide](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)basically you need to reinstall the ports

Comment: `xcode-select --install` does not work. It says that the software is not available. I ran `xcodebuild -license`, and afterwards in worked. Preiviously I alse uninstalled ports completely. I thought `sudo port selfupdate` should do download and install the most recent version of MacPorts. I'm stil not sure if it also does it after an OS X upgrade.

Comment: @R_User - self update has never been sufficient after an OSX upgrade. every OSX release has required a new version of Macports (one of 10.6-10.8 might not have but it was an exception)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the log file indicated my C compiler was not working.  xcodebuild -license solved the problem, though I had previously agreed to the license.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved for me opening XCode and agree.